# Cache Attacks on Cloud Infrastructures

Tags: timing-attack

I read something about cache attacks like this:

> Enter KSM (Kernel SamePage Merging). KSM enables the kernel to examine two or more already running programs and compare their memory. If any memory regions or pages are identical, KSM reduces multiple identical memory pages to a single page. This page is then marked copy on write. If the contents of the page is modified by a guest virtual machine virtual machine, a new page is created for that guest virtual machine. This means that cross-VM cache-timing attacks would now be possible.

I am confused about this statement:

> This means that cross-VM cache-timing attacks would now be possible.

Can someone explain about this?
[source link](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/07/02/its-all-a-question-of-time-aes-timing-attacks-on-openssl/)

Comment: You should add a link to the source of the statement.

Comment: Also, how is they specifically about Cryptograph and not [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Presumably it is because the guest vm can, by looking at timing values of writes, tell if a new page was created and the contents copied over.